# Full width fixed height content slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I looking for content slider with responsive full width and fixed height. Every slider have scaling - I don't want to scale slider. I found this slider:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Full-Width-Image-Slider-Plugin-responsiveSlides/
But this is only a image slider - I must have some html content in every slide. I don't need to have controls or pager - only autoplay.

Comment: What do you mean by scaling? What is it that you don’t want?

Comment: Check out this plugin: [http://slippry.com/](http://slippry.com/)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Slippry also scale image - I want to have fixed height. Exactly like on this example: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Full-Width-Image-Slider-Plugin-responsiveSlides/ if you resize window of browser - height of image in slider is still the same. Image is cropped by the sides.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [jquery content slider](http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Basic-Autoplay-Content-Slider-with-jQuery-CSS3.html)

you can have a basic idea of what you can do for an autoplay content slider

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/12-grab-cursor.html
which image and content can be displayed.